# catch class based on class name in variable

Tags: php

I can instantiate a class without knowing it's name in source code, like so:

```
function get_secret_instance($secret_class_name) {
    return new $secret_class_name();
}
```

Now, I want to throw and catch this one.

```
function throw_and_catch_secret_instance($secret_class_name) {
    try {
        throw new $secret_class_name();
    } catch ($secret_class_name $e) {
        echo "Got you ;)\n";
    }
}
```

However, apache logs a `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$secret_class_name' (T_VARIABLE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or namespace (T_NAMESPACE) or \\\\ (T_NS_SEPARATOR)`.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Short version: you can't, sorry

Comment: Why not just use `catch(Exception $e)` instead? That would catch all exceptions.

Comment: @iainn yea, didn't find that one, So I guess this one can be marked as dup.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson The idea normally should be to only catch what needs catching. But actually, that's what I'm doing right now, and as it seems, it's the only useful way to do it. (Except for me catching `Throwable` instead of `Exception`)

Answer (score 0):

My current solution/workaround is to use this construct:

```
} catch (Throwable $e) {
    if (strcmp(get_class($e), $secret_class_name)) {
        throw $e;
    }
    echo "Got you ;)\n";
}
```

Comment: `$e` will be an exception though so I'm not sure when it would ever be equal to `$secret_class_name`? Or are you, for some reason, manually instantiating exceptions?

Comment: `$e` is an exception, but `get_class($e)` is the name of it's class. That is the thing I'm comparing here.

Comment: Yes, and the class will be the exception (or class implementing the Throwable interface). Does all the classes you use implement the Throwable interface?

Comment: Yes, because you can't throw anything, that doesn't implement the `Throwable` interface.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php: "Throwable is the base interface for any object that can be thrown via a throw statement in PHP 7, including Error and Exception."

Comment: So in reality, all your classes extends from Exception, since according to the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php): _"PHP classes cannot implement the Throwable interface directly, and must instead extend Exception."_?

Comment: It looks that way, yes ;)

Comment: You should rethink your solution. Having everything extend Exception is just bad. And since PHP only support single inheritance, none of your classes will be able to extend anything else either. Create separate Exceptions for the situations that isn't covered by PHP's built in Exceptions and throw the one that makes sense.

Comment: I'm not perfectly sure what you assume I'm trying to do. In my understanding, something I throw is an exception and an exception class is basicly used for nothing else than handling the exception. So, why would I possibly want to inherit multiple classes there?

Comment: It think I might have misunderstood the question, but I read that your first code snippet `return new $secret_class_name` would, if something goes wrong, throw an exception and you want to see if the exception is that class, basically letting all classes throw themselves. I fail to see why you otherwise would need this since you can have multiple catch-blocks: `catch(ExceptionOne $e) {...} catch(ExceptionTwo $e) {...}` and so on. So if you want to do specific things on specific exceptions, you can do that without having it "dynamic". The code should know what to expect.

Comment: It's basically a lack of communication for why you would ever need this that threw (pardon the pun) me off.